# Port Forwarding my Minecraft Server not working with external IP

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, networking

I've started up a Minecraft server inside of VMWare on my laptop, the guest OS is Ubuntu

```
Host OS: Windows 10 (Version 20H2 OS Build 19042.867)
Guest: Ubuntu
Program: Minecraft 1.15
Java: OpenJDK 8
```

Guest Details

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

VMWare `VMware® Workstation 15 Pro` `15.5.6 build-16341506`

So it starts up just fine, here's netstat

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25565           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1174/java
```

The Networking is `Bridged` so that it has it's own proper IP on my router

- When I connect to the Local IP Address it connects just fine

I Port Forwarded it on my Spectrum Router, the default router the ISP gave me

```
Router Brand: Sagecom
Router Model: RAC2V1S
```

When I check with any website such as https://canyouseeme.org but others as well they all say they can see the port just fine. Just for the sake of testing I also entered a wrong port number and it said it could not see it so that's a vote of confidence.

```
Success: I can see your service on ###.###.###.### on port (25565)
Your ISP is not blocking port 25565
```

However all attempts to connect to it from my external/internet IP address (The one that's supposed to be port forwarded and the one that can reportedly be seen) result in this error message

```
Failed to connect to the server
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information:
```

I did a classic telnet check, sure enough it works from my local network

```
Trying ###.###.###.###...
Connected to ###.###.###.###.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

but sits there forever on the external/internet IP

```
Trying ###.###.###.###...
```

For note I even disabled literally all the security on the server and on my laptop and it still doesn't work, same situation, nothing changed.

I've been at this constantly for the last 6 hours and am at the point of giving up. I have no idea where this is going wrong. The ports open according to the website, the server is running fine, I can connect to it locally. I have no idea.

If anyone can help me it's much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried putting the port number at the end of the public IP the guest is trying to use? It be `###.###.###.###:25565`

Comment: @TimmyJim Yes I've also tried that, like I said it works just fine with either connecting on LAN but port number or not it simply won't connect using the internet ip address despite websites reporting the port is open

Comment: I'm going to assume it's either my router or not possible. Whenever I can afford a new router of my own I'll post back here and see if that fixed it.

Comment: Did OP ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue